# Why is my web app trying to connect to SQL Server Express when it's not supposed to?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I developed an ASP.NET MVC application that uses Microsoft's ASP.NET Identity with Oracle (not SQL Server). The application runs fine on my localhost, but when I publish it to the server (Windows 2008 R2), it throws this error shown below. It used to work before on the server; this error just started happening all of a sudden. The datastore for the Identity stuff is Oracle, not SQL Server Express. I don't have any connection string in my web.config that uses SQL Server Express.

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> SQL Server Express database file auto-creation error:
>
> The connection string specifies a local Sql Server Express instance using a database location within the application's App_Data directory. The provider attempted to automatically create the application services database because the provider determined that the database does not exist. The following configuration requirements are necessary to successfully check for existence of the application services database and automatically create the application services database:
>
> If the application is running on either Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008R2, special configuration steps are necessary to enable automatic creation of the provider database. Additional information is available at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=160102. If the application's App_Data directory does not already exist, the web server account must have read and write access to the application's directory. This is necessary because the web server account will automatically create the App_Data directory if it does not already exist.
>
> If the application's App_Data directory already exists, the web server account only requires read and write access to the application's App_Data directory. This is necessary because the web server account will attempt to verify that the Sql Server Express database already exists within the application's App_Data directory. Revoking read access on the App_Data directory from the web server account will prevent the provider from correctly determining if the SQL Server Express database already exists. This will cause an error when the provider attempts to create a duplicate of an already existing database. Write access is required because the web server account's credentials are used when creating the new database.
> SQL Server Express must be installed on the machine.
>
> The process identity for the web server account must have a local user profile. See the readme document for details on how to create a local user profile for both machine and domain accounts.
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager) +1524
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +706
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +57
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +1186
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +315
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +128
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +265
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +133
   System.Web.Management.SqlServices.GetSqlConnection(String server, String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String connectionString) +82

[HttpException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to SQL Server database.]
   System.Web.Management.SqlServices.GetSqlConnection(String server, String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String connectionString) +175
   System.Web.Management.SqlServices.SetupApplicationServices(String server, String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String connectionString, String database, String dbFileName, SqlFeatures features, Boolean install) +121
   System.Web.Management.SqlServices.Install(String database, String dbFileName, String connectionString) +57
```

Comment: Clearly something is trying to use SQL Server express. You'll need to create a [mcve], which will help narrow down the problem area.

Comment: But there is no reference anywhere in my Web.config to SQL Server Express

Comment: I didn't say it was in your web.config. Your errors are coming from a System.Web.Management namespace. Looks like it's some sort of application health monitoring. It's probably trying to log application health events to SQL Server. Again: you need to read the [mcve] guidance and narrow down where the problem area lays. You could either start by removing things one by one from your app until the problem goes away, or rebuild your app from scratch until the problem manifests itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem - I had put this setting in my Web.config:

<roleManager enabled="true"

Since roleManager is a provider set in Machine.config to use SQL Express, my app in turn tried o use SQL Express. As soon as I removed that roleManager setting from my web.config, my app worked. I guess you could also try to set it to enabled="false", but I just took it all out since I have no use for it.